# Adding JSON data to arrayList

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

Still working on this part of my script to parse my JSON `jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);` and then adding it to a arraylist "myJSONArray"

I am not sure how the for loop would work to add my elements from jsonArray into myJSONArray (arrayList)

If I am not clear please let me know and if there is any info I am missing just ask. Thanks in advance.

JSON data:

```
{"id":["1","2","3"],"name":["Dragon","Butterfly","Tattoo"],"thumb":["thm_polaroid.jpg","thm_default.jpg","thm_enhanced-buzz-9667-1270841394-4.jpg"],"path":["polaroid.jpg","default.jpg","enhanced-buzz-9667-1270841394-4.jpg"]}
```

image_data class:

```
public class image_data {


    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String thumb;
    public String path;


}
```

ShowThumb class:

```
public class showThumb extends Activity{



    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gridlayout);

         Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
         String jsonData = bundle.getString("jsonData");


         JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonData);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ArrayList<image_data> myJSONArray = new ArrayList<image_data>();

         for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
               **//This is where I think I create the seperate arrays of id name thumb and path**
             myJSONArray.add(new image_data());

         }


GridView gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this,image_data));

    }
}
```

Comment: Show the JSON output..or at least part of it to have representation what objects need to be parsed.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to arrange for the JSON data to be the other way around - an array of objects, rather than an object of arrays.

Comment: @Karl The JSON data came out of my MySQL query -> json_encode that way. Would I alter my query to pull the data in a different order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How you iterate and add

```
 for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length;i++)
    {    
         JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
         imgnfo.id =  json_data.getInt("id_key");
         imgnfo.name = json_data.getString("name_key");
         imgnfo.thumb = json_data.getString("thumb_key");
         imgnfo.info = json_data.getString("info_key");
         myArray.add(new image_data());
    }
```

Just add proper keys names. I didn't know them.

Comment: @Nikola  can you share the response that you are getting with the for loop.

Answer (score 2):

Yo should post what the json data looks like.
Assuming the json data looks something like

```
...,{
    "image_data": {
        "name": "image name","thumb":"thumbpath","path":"path"}
},{
    "image_data": {
        "name": "image name 2","thumb":"thumbpath 2","path":"path 2"}
}
```

Then you would extract the values like so:

```
    ArrayList<image_data> imageArray = new ArrayList<image_data>();

         for (int i=0; i<jsonArray.length(); i++) {
             image_data img = new image_data();

             Object jo = jsonArray.get(i);

             image_data.name = jo.name;
             image_data.thumb = jo.thumb;
             image_data.path = jo.path;

             imageArray.add(new image_data());

         }
```

Consider using getters for you image_data class.
Also consider renaming it to ImageData

Comment: sorry I edited my post and added the json layout. +1 thanks your post was helpful.